# Can we show a Shared Mail Box calendar inside SharePoint modern page

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, office-365, calendar

We have a Shared Mailbox calendar inside Office 365 for showing the Holidays & Leaves. Now can we embed/show this calendar inside SharePoint modern page?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the mailbox is linked to a Microsoft 365 group, then you can display calendar entries from that group using the group calendar web part.

[Use the Group calendar web part](https://support.microsoft.com/office/use-the-group-calendar-web-part-eaf3c04d-5699-48cb-8b5e-3caa887d51ce)

Comment: unfortunately  the mailbox is not connected/linked to MS 365 group.. so what are options i have? thanks

Comment: Build your own web part?